# Bloquear capturas de pantalla en Windows con C# y SetWindowDisplayAffinity

Tags: c#, windows, windows10

He visto que en algunos documentos protegidos de office al hacer una captura de pantalla la ventana de office aparece en negro y el resto de la captura normal. He visto en algunas otras preguntas que eso se hace gracias al método `SetWindowDisplayAffinity`

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr hwnd, DisplayAffinity affinity);
```

Pero no se como puedo llamarlo y desde dónde, he intentado hacerlo de la siguiente forma en el método donde inicializo la ventana pero no funciona, siempre devuelve false.

```
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            SetWindowDisplayAffinity(GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), DisplayAffinity.Monitor);

        }
```

No se si es que debo llamarle desde algún punto o es que los métodos de otras DLL no se ejecutan así.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42351731)

Comment: @Pikoh si, ya la he visto pero con el código que pone no me funciona